# How to implement Cordova white list plugin in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been following numerous blogs and tutorials on how to achieve this but with no luck. I have a feeling that I'm missing a step in the process (most likely something that is so obvious, the authors of the tutorials don't feel it necessary to mention). I'm using the [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) for my apps, and was following [this tutorial](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist).

First I run this from the cli:

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

I then add this in my config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Yet I still don't think this is working. Is there something I need to do in my index.html? My app.js perhaps? I'm a little lost here.

PS - I can see that the `'cordova-plugin-whitelist'` folder is in my `[app root]/plugins/` directory. But again, I have a feeling I should reference it somewhere.

**UPDATE**

I added the following to my `index.html` file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

However when do do that I get the following errors in my app:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

(index):99 Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
(anonymous function) @ (index):99
angular-google-maps.min.js:5 Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=&language=en&sensor=false&callback=onGoogleMapsReady773' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable script loading from HTTPS urls in your content-security-policy meta tag:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https:;
```

You could restrict to the specific google domains:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.googleapis.com https://maps.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'
```

Comment: thanks, I would like zero restrictions throughout the app for the moment. I find that restrictions get in the way while developing. What would my full meta tag look like if I wanted to open it up to everything?

Comment: I think you could try with `script-src 'self'  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:;`